# Using Handler and postDelayed to update ListView

Tags: android

**Question**

Is repeatedly posting and removing `Message` objects to a `Handler` considered acceptable? I'm using this mechanism to wait for a certain delay after a callback that happens multiple times.

**Background**

I have a ListView with fairly complex views. Each view has a few text components and a sizeable ImageView. I'm trying to solve some jerkiness while it is scrolling.

I've already converted it to use the drawing cache to reduce spurious drawing. I've added a mechanism for delaying the load of the Bitmap in the ImageView until the scrolling stops.

This mechanism uses ListView `OnScrollListener.onScroll(...)` (since I found `onScrollStateChanged(...)` to be unreliable). Whenever `onScroll` is fire, I post a `Message` to a `Handler` using `postDelayed(message, 200)` after removing existing messages of the same type.

The result is a bunch of post and removes to the `Handler` and, when one eventually gets processed, all the images are loaded. I am wondering if repeated posting and removing messages from a Handler is going to cause a problem? I haven't hit one yet but if there is an alternative, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Can you post your ListAdapter? I understand that your question is about handlers, but I suspect the handler may have an issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and removing messages was not costly until the system became busy. Then it became unreliable as the main thread would get tied up drawing. Instead I switched to an on off mechanism for the component that needed notification and that seemed to alleviate a lot of the issue.